# C# Keyword not supportet - CertificateFile - MySqlConnection

Tags: c#, mysql, certificate

I am trying to establish a SSL connection to a MySQL Server.

Now I get the following error, when trying to connect:

```
Unhandled Exception:

System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported.
Parameter name: CertificateFile
```

here is my Connection String:

```
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(
   "database=database;user=sslclient;" +
   "CertificateFile=C:\\Users\\LSP\\documents\\visual studio 2017\\Projects\\App1\\App1\\client.pfx;" +
   "CertificatePassword=XXX;" +
   "SSL Mode=Required");
```

Do you know what the fault is ? As mentioned in

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-ssl.html

it is valid.

I also tried to manage this with a MySqlConnectionStringBuilder, but this also dont work:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYGYN.png)

I am using the newest Version of MySql.Data from the NuGet Manager.

Thank you for you help,

Louis

Comment: Are you missing some semicolons in the connection string, or is this just a typo in your text above?

Comment: I copied this string from the tutorial (see second link). But I also corrected it, see above now.

Comment: did you try to put certificate to path without spaces within? or put the path into ''?

Comment: That is not the fault, VS reports to me. I think, that the library from MySQL (MySQL.Data), which i installed from NuGet packet manager does not contain this. I think i need to install the right package manually.

Comment: Okay, I downloaded a version from oracle, now it is working!